# Django - how to obtain the latest related model in an efficent way I can iterate on the template?

Tags: django, database, performance, django-models, django-templates

Let's say I have two related models, one of the two with a datetime field.
(Author & Book with a pub_date).

I want to display a list of authors and the latest book each of them has written.
I made a method on the `Author` model:

```
def get_latest_book(self):
    return self.books.all().latest('pub_date')
```

That is working, but it's very inefficent when it comes to be rendered on a template:

views.py:

```
class AuthorListView(ListView):
    model = Author
    template_name = 'author_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by('name').prefetch_related('books')
```

author_list.html:

```
...
{% for author in author_list %}
Name: {{author.name}} - Latest publication: {{author.get_latest_book}}
{% endfor %}
...
```

This is generating a large number of queries like:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `app_book` WHERE `app_book`.`author_id` = 374 ORDER BY `app_book`.`pub_date` DESC LIMIT 1
  36 similar queries.
```

for each Author I have in the database!
This results in huge loading times for the book list.

How can I print on the template a list of Authors with their latest book in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to boost efficiency is with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class AuthorListView(ListView):
    model = Author
    template_name = 'author_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            owner=self.request.user
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('books', Book.objects.order_by('-pub_date'), to_attr='books_ordered')
        ).order_by('name')
```

and then render this with:

```
{% for author in author_list %}
    Name: {{author.name}} - Latest publication: {{ author.books_ordered.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

This however will load all related books in memory, but in a single query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked and cut down my queries and loading times. The only thing that isn't clear to me is your last statement: is loading all related items in memory in a single query a bad thing? What should I prefer to use for the best performance?

Comment: @Willem , what do yo think of this : Book.objects.all().order_by('author', '-pubdate').distinct('author') except it won't work if database doesnt accept distinct ?

Comment: @EricMartin: well as far as I know, Django only does this for the PostgreSQL database (and this might be the only database that supports this), but furthermore it would not include `Author`s that did not publish any book yet.